# Display Local notification with Custom time intervals in Android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Android PhoneGap. I want to display local notification, I refered some links about local notification, I got some information from the following links,

https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin/tree/master/android-statusbar-notificaion

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification

I tried both link that `LocalNotification` link is working fine, but here I want to set date and time like alarm, the above `LocalNotification` link have Alarm classes, but I am not getting clearly, I don't know how to use alarm in local notification in android Phonegap.

otherwise

if possible for set date and time in android phonegap Toast notification?

Comment: Try This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720071/cordova-local-notification-android-plugin-2-2-upgrade