# Using Cordova's Local Notification Plugin For Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, localnotification

I'm trying to alert notifications using phonegap's [local Notification Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification), and it alerts notifications when the application runs, but I don't know how can I configure it to alert plugins on specific times.

Here's the function that does the notification action:

```
plugins.localNotification.add({ date: new Date(), message: 'Test', id: 123 });
```

when I tried to put:

```
date: new Date(12,09,09,2,00,00)
```

It didn't display any alerts. So, how can I modify it to work with different dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/) DatePicker for Android, which returns the datetime in this form:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ.
```

So, it's different from the form the form the plugin uses ... [For how to upgrade the plugin to work with 2.2 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720071/cordova-local-notification-android-plugin-2-2-upgrade) Question]

So I tried this solution to alert notifications at specific dates:

```
 if (typeof plugins !== "undefined")
                       {
                        var RId = 0;
                        var rDate =new Date();
                        var RemDate = reminder_deadline.split("T")[0];
                        var RemTimeB = reminder_deadline.split("T")[1];
                        var RemTime = RemTimeB.split("Z")[0];
                        var RYear = RemDate.split("-")[0];
                        var RMonth = RemDate.split("-")[1];
                        var RMonth = RMonth-1;
                        var RDay = RemDate.split("-")[2];
                        var RHour = RemTime.split(":")[0];
                        var RMinute = RemTime.split(":")[1];
                        var RSecond = RemTime.split(":")[2];
                        alert(RYear+".."+RMonth+".."+RDay+".."+RHour+".."+RMinute+".."+RSecond);
                        rDate.setFullYear(RYear);
                        rDate.setMonth(RMonth);
                        rDate.setDate(RDay);
                        rDate.setHours(RHour);
                        rDate.setMinutes(RMinute);
                        rDate.setSeconds(RSecond);
                        plugins.localNotification
                        .add({ 
                            date: rDate,
                            message: reminder_name, 
                            id: RId
                             });
                             }
                             RId++;
             }
```

Hope it helps :)